# Change Thunars default "copy of" tags

Tags: xubuntu, customization, thunar

Is there any way other than hacking the source to change the tags that Thunar adds when you copy & paste files.

ie..
copy & paste of *file.txt*

3 times results in:

- **copy of** *file.txt*
- **another copy of** *file.txt*
- **third copy of** *file.txt*

I'd like to change it to something that increments to the end of the filename so the copies stay grouped with the original file in the default name sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design decision of the thunar authors, hard-coded and not yet configurable. If you don't like it, tell [them](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9179). You can always fork the code or patch it for your own pleasure, provided you can code in c or persuade or blackmail someone else to do the work for you.